EF Core saves incorrect data to timestamp with time zone when using HasDefaultValueSql()
I work with EF Core and PostgreSQL.
When configuring an entity I use this code:
modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
            .Property("Created")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("timezone('utc', NOW())");

And when I add new entity to the database, it saves it with the wrong time. I live on +3 time zone, so saved datetime should be -3 from my current time. But it saves it with -6 from my current time, which is not how I expect utc time work.
But when I add data to db from PgAdmin, it saves it with correct time in utc time zone.
How to fix this? And why does it happen?
I tried using
.HasDefaultValue(DateTime.UtcNow)

But it only calculates during migration creation and doesn't work as default value I want.
Also when I use
.HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()");

It saves time from EF Core like utc time, but when I save from pgAdmin it saves in my local time.

Sounds like double conversion, your config is just the default value which should work because the value is resolved in the database. Please post the actual schema of your table/class, and the logic that is providing the record. If you override the default with a physical value then that will be used instead

What's the field's data type?

As i understand, problem is with timezone(). It returns timestamp without timezone, and my column type is timestamp with time zone, so after coversion it saves my current timezone. So just using NOW() will be ok, since I get data throw ef core it will apply timezone and return me time in utc

@GXtal there doesn't seem to be anything wrong.  timestamp with time zone doesn't store the offset. No matter what you provide the stored value is UTC: the internally stored value is always in UTC and gets automatically converted to local time when queried. When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone

The docs also explain that NOW() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are equivalent, returning a timestamp with time zone. should be -3 from my current time it shouldn't, you should get the original time back, precisely because the UTC value will get converted to local time. The fact you got -6 means there was a manual attempt to "fix" the offset, doubling it. As others asked, what's the actual field type? Is it timestamp with time zone or timestamp without time zone ?

If the default value works correctly when you run queries directly via PgAdmin, then this is confirmation that the configuration is correct!

But when I add data to db from PgAdmin, it saves it with correct time in utc time zone.

However, if the data values are not what you expect when you insert records through your code, then you need to check what values your code is sending to the database.
Note that HasDefaultValueSql will define a default value constraint on the table in the database schema that can be applied to the database during migrations. Once applied to the schema, the default value script will only be executed for inserts that do NOT specify a value for the constrained field.

Default values - EF Core

In other words, the default value will only be used if your code does not send a value for the Created field.
To do that you can make the field nullable and leave the value unassigned to allow the field to be ignored on inserts by EF and to allow the database to set the value.

I live on +3 time zone, so saved datetime should be -3 from my current time. But it saves it with -6 from my current time

This is a clear indication that your code is specifically setting the value for the Created field before the record is sent to the database, the fact that the value is out by 2 times your local timezone offset indicates your code that is setting this value is compensating for the local timezone twice, most likely the value is already set to UTC and then you are applying a timezone conversion again.

It may help to edit your post and include the code that you are using to create the record and to add it to the context.
It is still a common practise for Audit fields like Created and Modified to be set using triggers instead of directly through EF Core. Your EF code is still valid for redundancy but your trigger can override any values sent through from the EF context.


My code didn't send any data in Created column, error heppend becouse NOW() works correctly and when i tried to use timezone('utc', NOW()) i compensated timezone twice. Thaks for your help
